# How to remove a folder with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

If I build with Turbostudio a portable and use it later, there are two folders created on host that should be removed with a batch file. These are the two folders:

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Turbo.net
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\SPOON
```

In `SPOON` is created additionally the subfolder `CACHE`.

I found a code from **matt** that is working on temp folder:

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)

REM --&gt; Check for permissions
&gt;nul 2&gt;&amp;1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --&gt; If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) &gt; "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 &gt;&gt; "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"

:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code ends)
:: Your codes should start from the following line
@echo off
cd %temp%
rd /S /Q %temp%
```

But how I can remove the `Turbo.net` folder in `Local`?

Comment: Read about predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) like `LOCALAPPDATA` or `TEMP` and open a command prompt window and run `rd /?` for help on remove directory command. The entire code for running the batch file with elevated permissions of a local administrator is not needed to delete the directories in `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and `%TEMP%`, except the batch file should delete them for all user accounts on a Windows machine.

Comment: By the way: C and C++ have library functions to delete files and folders and change attributes. Temporary files and folders created by the application should be deleted also by the portable application before exit without usage of a batch file. See for example file related functions in [stdio.h (C) or cstdio (C++)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/). On Stack Overflow there are lots of code snippets for [deleting files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+delete+file+directory) or change attributes for C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the folder for your current user, simply use the user environment for it. To get info on your environment, open `cmd.exe` run `set` each of the environment variables are defined as a name, followed by a value, i.e.

```
APPDATA=C:\Users\USER123\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\USER123\AppData\Local
```

To use a variable in batch, you simply wrap the name of it in `%` to get the value. So to delete your `Turbo.net` folder, simply add this line to the bottom off your script.

```
rd /S /Q "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Turbo.net"
```

Exactly the same as you did with directory for temporary files which should be enclosed also in double quotes and should have `SPOON` appended:

```
rd /S /Q "%TEMP%\SPOON"
```

If you executed `set` you would have seen `temp=` defined as a variable. You can simply do `echo %temp%` and `echo %localappdata%` to see the values of each.

To change the attribute of the folder, use command `attrib`.

You can decide what attributes you plan on changing, but as a hint, run `attrib /?` from cmd to see the help.

As an example:

```
attrib -H "%localappdata%\Turbo.net"
```

This command line removes hidden attribute of the folder where `+H` would add the attribute.